# Google Sheets: Freeze vs Protect?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I have a sheet (screenshot attached) . The first 3 rows are header rows and are frozen . I noticed that a formula that I'd put into U3 in the header

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"days since";IFERROR(IF(V4:V*1<>0,DATEDIF(V4:V,TODAY(),"D"),))})
```

was gone with just "days since" in that cell. Then I removed "days since" and refreshed the browser. I expected this to be protected, but it did not reappear (screenshot) . Is this normal behaviour. If so how do you protect header rows from change?

Answer (score 1):

To "freeze" a row is not synonymous with "protecting" a row.

When you Freeze a row, for ex. by dragging the freeze bar between row 3 and 4 in your screenshot, you are locking them in place from a UI perspective. This means that those rows will stay at the top of the screen even as the user scrolls down through the worksheet.

Ex: This is helpful when you want to make sure the column headers are always visible.

When you "Protect" a row, range, or sheet, you are locking users out of editing them without warning or permission.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

That page helps describe how to Protect a sheet or a range. in particular:

1. Open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
2. Click Data and then Protected sheets and ranges. A box will open on the right.
3. Click Add a sheet or range or click an existing protection to edit it. To protect a range, click Range.
4. Range: To change or enter the range you’re protecting, click the spreadsheet icon and highlight the range in the spreadsheet.
5. Click Set permissions or Change permissions

From there you can define what permissions you'd like to apply.